# Rally: Get user _ref from RallyRestApi object created using ApiKey

Tags: rally

I created a connection to rally using the ApiKey constructor.

> Question is how do i find out the User "_ref" associated with this User ApiKey ?

```
rallyRestApi= new RallyRestApi(new URI(host), "myApiKey");
```

I tried following 2 test runs:

1. doing a blank query (i.e. without any setQueryFilter) on User object; it returns me all the users.

   QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
   QueryResponse userQueryResponse = connection.query(userRequest);
   JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
2. Getting owner from Workspace object  >> This returns me the owner of the Workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get a current user:

```
GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest("/user");
GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
JsonObject currentUser = getResponse.getObject();
String currentUserName = currentUser.get("_refObjectName").getAsString();
String currentUserRef = currentUser.get("_ref").getAsString();
System.out.println("current user: " + currentUserName + currentUserRef);
```

I tested it with latest [Rally API toolkit for Java](https://github.com/RallyCommunity/rally-java-rest-apps).